# Adding shadow above horizontal scrollbar in tableview

Tags: javafx

I am trying to indicate to my users that there is additional data in the table if they scroll down and I'd like to do this using a shadow effect. How can I add the shadow above the horizontal scroll bar?

Comment: I'd rely on the host scrollbar appearance, but you might be able "to create a custom `rowFactory` that replaces an entire row of a `TableView`."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Considering all the different conditions, One way I can think of to fix this is to include a node into the inner children of the TableView. This way I will have better control of the effect.

If you are OK to use the lookup method and tweak the children of TableView, then you may consider the below approach :).

The general idea is :

- We will create a pane of desired height for showing the effect. I am using background-color of the pane for a better control of the effect color, size, etc.
- Then we include this node into the Group that contains the TableRows.
- Based on the dimensions of the TableView viewport, we position this pane.
- For handling the visibility of the effect, we access the virtual scroll bar and listen for its visibility and the scroll value.

Summarizing  all the above, below is a quick demo to show the shadow effect. Notice that the shadow does no overlap the scrollbars, because we included the pane in the Group node that holds TableRows.

**UPDATE:**
I updated the below demo to include a `FadeTransition` for a more smooth visibility of the shade.

[image]

```
import javafx.animation.FadeTransition;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.InvalidationListener;
import javafx.beans.binding.Bindings;
import javafx.beans.property.BooleanProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleBooleanProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ScrollBar;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.layout.Region;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;

public class TableViewShadowForScrollDemo extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        ObservableList<Person> persons = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
            persons.add(new Person("Name " + i, "Last" + i, "City " + i));
        }

        TableColumn<Person, String> fnCol = new TableColumn<>("First Name");
        fnCol.setCellValueFactory(param -> param.getValue().firstNameProperty());

        TableColumn<Person, String> lnCol = new TableColumn<>("Last Name");
        lnCol.setCellValueFactory(param -> param.getValue().lastNameProperty());

        TableColumn<Person, String> cityCol = new TableColumn<>("City");
        cityCol.setCellValueFactory(param -> param.getValue().lastNameProperty());
        fnCol.setPrefWidth(150);
        lnCol.setPrefWidth(100);
        cityCol.setPrefWidth(200);

        MyTableView<Person> tableView = new MyTableView<>();
        tableView.getColumns().addAll(fnCol, lnCol, cityCol);
        tableView.setItems(persons);

        StackPane root = new StackPane(tableView);
        root.setPadding(new Insets(15));
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 500, 300);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.setTitle("TableView Scroll Shadow Demo");
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    class MyTableView<S> extends TableView<S> {
        private final double SHADOW_HEIGHT = 40;

        private Group sheet;

        private StackPane shade;

        private Rectangle clip;

        private BooleanProperty show;

        @Override
        protected void layoutChildren() {
            super.layoutChildren();
            // Ensuring that we set the configurations only once.
            if (sheet == null) {
                show = new SimpleBooleanProperty();
                // Create a pane for creating the shadow. I choose to use background-color instead of effect for better control of the effect.
                shade = new StackPane();
                shade.setMouseTransparent(true);
                shade.setStyle("-fx-background-color:linear-gradient(to top, #999999, transparent 70%, transparent);");

                // Access the Group node to which the shade has to be included.
                sheet = (Group) lookup(".sheet");
                final ObservableList<Node> sheetChildren = sheet.getChildren();
                sheetChildren.add(shade);
                // Ensure to always keep the shade on top of all table row nodes.
                sheet.needsLayoutProperty().addListener((obs, old, needsLayout) -> {
                    if (!needsLayout && sheetChildren.indexOf(shade) != sheetChildren.size() - 1) {
                        sheetChildren.remove(shade);
                        sheetChildren.add(shade);
                    }
                });

                // Get the clipped container for position calculations of the shade.
                Region clipCont = (Region) lookup(".clipped-container");
                clip = (Rectangle) clipCont.getClip();
                // Add listener to resize/reposition the shade, when ever the table dimensions are changed
                InvalidationListener listener = e -> {
                    shade.resize(sheet.getLayoutBounds().getWidth(), SHADOW_HEIGHT);
                    shade.setLayoutY(clip.getLayoutY() + clipCont.getHeight() - SHADOW_HEIGHT);
                };
                clipCont.widthProperty().addListener(listener);
                clipCont.heightProperty().addListener(listener);

                // Access the vertical scroll bar for deciding the visibility of the shade.
                ScrollBar vBar = (ScrollBar) lookup(".scroll-bar:vertical");
                FadeTransition fadeTransition = new FadeTransition(Duration.millis(500), shade);
                fadeTransition.setOnFinished(e -> shade.setVisible(show.get()));
                show.addListener((obs, old, val) -> {
                    if (val) {
                        shade.setVisible(true);
                    }
                    fadeTransition.setFromValue(val ? 0.0 : 1.0);
                    fadeTransition.setToValue(val ? 1.0 : 0.0);
                    fadeTransition.play();
                });
                show.bind(Bindings.createBooleanBinding(() -> vBar.isVisible() && vBar.getValue() < 1.0, vBar.visibleProperty(), vBar.valueProperty()));
            }
        }
    }

    class Person {
        private StringProperty firstName = new SimpleStringProperty();
        private StringProperty lastName = new SimpleStringProperty();
        private StringProperty city = new SimpleStringProperty();

        public Person(String fn, String ln, String cty) {
            setFirstName(fn);
            setLastName(ln);
            setCity(cty);
        }

        public String getFirstName() {
            return firstName.get();
        }

        public StringProperty firstNameProperty() {
            return firstName;
        }

        public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
            this.firstName.set(firstName);
        }

        public String getLastName() {
            return lastName.get();
        }

        public StringProperty lastNameProperty() {
            return lastName;
        }

        public void setLastName(String lastName) {
            this.lastName.set(lastName);
        }

        public String getCity() {
            return city.get();
        }

        public StringProperty cityProperty() {
            return city;
        }

        public void setCity(String city) {
            this.city.set(city);
        }
    }
}
```