# Javafx TreeTableview enable default scrollbar visibility on touch enabled devices

Tags: javafx

On touch enabled devices the scrollbars of a table view (I am using a tree table view) are not visible until the user starts scrolling. This makes it so that sometimes you cannot tell if there is additional content in the table until you strt scrolling. My goal is either to:

1. Disable this behavior (but the virtual flow doesn't provide this functionality)
2. Or to programmatically determine if the scrollbar should be visible and to manually change the visibility.

Given that most of the virtual flow fields and methods are private, how can I go about achieving this?

Comment: I don't advise changing the default behavior.  For instance, in Safari on an iPhone, for a scrollable web page, no scroll bar is shown until the scroll begins, exactly as you describe for the touch JavaFX app in your question.  Instead [add an indicator that there is more content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76562899/adding-shadow-above-horizontal-scrollbar-in-tableview), which is separate from the scroll bar.

Comment: @jewelsea I have considered this but the issue is that the visibility of the shadow is bound to the visibility of the scrollbar.